# Question about Vitali Covering (from a Lemma in Royden and Fitzpatrick's book)

Tags: measure-theory

> **Definition.** For a real valued function $f$ and an interior point $x$ of its domain, the **upper** **derivative** of $f$ at $x$ denoted by $\overline{D}f(x)$ is defined as follows: $$\overline{D}f(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\left[ \sup \left \{\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}: 0<|t|\leq h \right \} \right]$$

A Lemma in Royden and Fitzpatrick's Real Analysis book says:

**Lemma.** Let $f$ be an increasing function on the closed, bounded interval $[a,b]$. Then for each $\alpha>0$, $$m^*\{x\in (a,b) : \overline{D}f(x) \geq 
\alpha \} \leq \frac{1}{\alpha}[f(b)-f(a)].$$

The book proceeds to prove this by:

> Let $\alpha>0$. Define $E_{\alpha}:=\{x\in (a,b): \overline{D}f(x)\geq\alpha \}$. Choose $\alpha' \in (0,\alpha)$. Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the collection of closed, bounded intervals $[c,d]$ contained in $(a,b)$ for which $f(d)-f(c)\geq \alpha ' (d-c)$. Since $\overline{D}f\geq \alpha$ on $E_{\alpha}$, $\mathscr{F}$ is a Vitali covering for $E_{\alpha}$.

I can follow the rest of the proof, but why is the statement above true? In particular, why is $\mathscr{F}\neq \emptyset$, and why is it a Vitali covering for $E_{\alpha}$? I have an inkling that it might be due to the fact that $f$ is increasing in $(a,b)$ and thus it can only have a countable number of discontinuity on it, but I can't quite get a solid grasp of it.

Answer (score 4):

Take any $x \in E_\alpha$. Now, since $\overline{D}f(x)\geq\alpha$, it follows that for some small $\delta$, $t<\delta \implies\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}\geq\alpha'$.

(The definition for the upper derivative above is slightly wrong, I will edit it)

Putting $t=d-x$, this means that $t<\delta \implies f(d)-f(x) \geq \alpha'(d-x)$. The interval $[d,x]$ is in $\mathscr{F}$ for every $d$ close enough to $x$,for arbitrary $x$ in $E_\alpha$. This makes $\mathscr{F}$ a Vitali covering for $E_\alpha$.

Comment: Was that $\delta$ constructed from the definition of upper derivative?

Comment: Yes, since the limit exists, by definition of the limit, after some $h$ the supremum term will have to be closer to $\alpha$ than $\alpha '$ is.

Comment: In the latter part of your answer, is $\epsilon$ an arbitrary positive real number?

Comment: I'm still not sure why the implication $t< \epsilon \implies f(d)-f(x) \geq \alpha ' (d-x)$ works because I don't know if $\epsilon$ is arbitrary. Or do we vary $d$ to compensate?

Comment: Read next comment.

Comment: Yes, the $d$ varies, because the $x$ and the $\delta$ are both fixed. What I am saying is that **for all $d$ satisfying $d-x<\delta$**, the interval $[d,x] \in \mathscr{F}$. Thus $\mathscr{F}$ is non-empty and a Vitali covering for the set $E_\alpha$.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm starting to annoy you, I worked it out again, and I realized I have not understood your construction. I started with the limit definition of upper derivative, something like: for $\alpha ' /2$, there is a $\delta >0$ such that for $z\in (0,\infty)$, $z<\delta \implies | \sup \left  \{\frac{f(x+t)}{t}: 0<|t|\leq h \right \} -\overline{D}f(x)|<\alpha ' /2$. Is this correct? Also, you mentioned that there's something wrong with my upper derivative definition?

Comment: I mean $\sup \left \{\frac{f(x+t)}{t}: 0<|t|\leq z \right \}$

Comment: @Kurome No problem, it is your right to question me till I clarify myself.  However, I really do think there is something wrong with your definition. You know the definition of derivative, shouldn't the definition of upper derivative then be $\sup \{ \frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t} : 0 < |t| \leq z\}$? With this definition everything goes through. I don't think the definition you have is correct. For example, let $f(x)$ be a constant function, say $f(x) \equiv 76$. The upper derivative is $\limsup_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+t)}{t}$, which will be $\limsup_{h \to 0} \frac{76}{t}$, which is infinite for all $x$.

Comment: Where $t$ above is such that $0 < |t| \leq h$. It doesn't make a difference: there is something wrong with the definition. You should check Royden once again. I have Royden, but I think it's the book he wrote by himself, because I don't see a Fitzpatrick.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That was a terrible typo. It's embarrassing that I even copied it to my comments. Anyway, can you comment on my initial construction above? With the definition corrected in mind of course.

Comment: @Kurome I am happy that you have realized. On your initial construction, it's true that the function $f$ is discontinuous at countably many points, but then, we know *absolutely nothing* about $f$ at these points, other than the fact that the left and right limits exist and are not equal. The point is, to show that $\mathscr{F}$ is a Vitali covering, you don't need to use the fact that  $f$ is increasing. Royden will have written somewhere later in the proof "because $f$ is increasing" (I think he does it while evaluating some sum), and I don't...

Comment: think that $f$ increasing can be used in providing a shorter proof that $\mathscr{F}$ is a Vitali covering. But I liked your question, it was very provocative and interesting. Thank you, and +1.